# Calculate size in megabytes from SQL varbinary field

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a db table that stores files as varbinary(MAX). When we run the following script:

```
SELECT SUM(LEN(Content)) FROM dbo.File
```

The result is:

> 35398663

I want to convert this number into megabytes? Is this possible?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use [`DATALENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) to retrieve the number of bytes and then convert, like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6df92/291)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     type varchar(20), 
     details varchar(30)
    );
 
INSERT INTO supportContacts
(type, details)
VALUES
('Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com'),
('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *, gigabytes / 1024.0 as terabytes
from (
  select *, megabytes / 1024.0 as gigabytes
  from (
    select *, kilobytes / 1024.0 as megabytes
    from (
      select *, bytes / 1024.0 as kilobytes
      from (
        select sum(datalength(details)) as bytes
        from supportContacts       
      ) a
    ) b  
  ) c
) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6df92/291/0)**:

```
| bytes | kilobytes |     megabytes |      gigabytes |         terabytes |
|-------|-----------|---------------|----------------|-------------------|
|    29 |   0.02832 | 0.00002765625 | 2.700805664e-8 | 2.63750553125e-11 |
```

Comment: And +1 for SQL Fiddle. There goes the rest of my day :)

Comment: This number may be better written (in code) 
 and easier to understand and remember
 if expressed as a factor of 1024

Comment: SELECT   sum ( datalength(Content) )   /1024.0 /1024.0 /1024.0 )    --GB

Comment: SELECT   sum ( datalength(Content) )   /1024.0 /1024.0         )    --MB

Comment: SELECT   sum ( datalength(Content) )   /1024.0                 )    --KB

Comment: SELECT   sum ( datalength(Content) )                 )    --Bytes

Answer (score 2):

A friendly update to economize the solution query, for any who come across this post:

- only sums the datalength once
- avoids repetitive division and joining

```
select bytes
    , bytes / 1024.0 as kilobytes
    , bytes / power(1024.0,2) as megabytes
    , bytes / power(1024.0,3) as gigabytes
    , bytes / power(1024.0,4) as terabytes
from
(
    select sum(datalength(details)) as bytes
    from supportContacts
) a
```